# Set jQuery Validator to be based off ID

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have a form with 5 dropdowns that are generated by php at run time that I want to have validated using jQuery validator. Due to the fact that I have given them an array for the name, validator will only validate the first dropdown, but I need to ensure all 5 are being validated before posting my form.

PHP for making the dropdown

```
function activityDropDown($id){
      echo('<select id='.$id.' name=activity[]>
          <option></option>
          <option>a</option>
          <option>b</option>  
          <option>c</option>
        </select>');
}
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#friDate").Zebra_DatePicker({
            format: 'm-d-Y',
            disabled_dates: ['* * * 0-4,6'],
            first_day_of_week: 0,
            onSelect: function(){
                var date = new Date($("#friDate").val());
                $("#mon").val(addDays(date, -4));
                $("#tue").val(addDays(date, -3));
                $("#wed").val(addDays(date, -2));
                $("#thu").val(addDays(date, -1));
                $("#fri").val(addDays(date, 0));        
            }
        });
        $("#form").validate();
        $("#monActivity").rules("add", {
            required: true
        });
        $("#tueActivity").rules("add", {
            required: true
        });
    });
</script>
            <tr>
                <td>Activity:</td>
                <td><?php activityDropDown('monActivity') ?></td>
                <td><?php activityDropDown('tueActivity') ?></td>
                <td><?php activityDropDown('wedActivity') ?></td>
                <td><?php activityDropDown('thuActivity') ?></td>
                <td><?php activityDropDown('friActivity') ?></td>
            </tr>
```

As you can see, I have tried to manually add the rules based off the elements ID, but it is still doing the same thing; only the first dropdown will validate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function activityDropDown($id){
      static $activitynum = 0;
      echo("<select id='$id' name=activity[$activitynum]>
          <option></option>
          <option>a</option>
          <option>b</option>  
          <option>c</option>
        </select>");
      $activitynum++;
}
```

This works around the limitation in the validation plugin by specifying the array indexes explicitly, so the names are distinct.

Comment: Thank you! You are a scholar and a saint! That worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around `id`

```
echo('<select id="'.$id.'" name="activity[]">
```

Comment: That's embarassing! Thankyou, but that did not solve my issue. It is still only validating the first dropdown

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console..and can you do a `console.log($("#monActivity"))` when calling `$("#monActivity").rules("add", {
            required: true
        });`..just to check if the elements are present at that time..

Comment: It is a problem in the plugin, it stores the handler by name, it by default takes only first element of the name..there have been fixes posted a lot of places.. try this..http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/05/27/jquery-validation-for-array-of-input-elements/